# How many elements in one column are linked to an element other column?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sum, clause

Consider I have two tables

```
Courses            Program
---------------------------
course_ID          program_id
course_title       program_name   
program_ID
```

Now, I want to check no of courses(by course_id) offered by each program (program_id).

Comment: Post the structure of both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.program_id ,p.program_name, count(course_id)
from courses c
join Program p on c.Program_id =p.Program_id
group by program_id,program_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're searching for a `GROUP BY` and a corresponding aggregate.

```
--Creating sample tables and data
SELECT course_ID, course_title, program_ID
INTO #courses
FROM (
    VALUES  (0, 'course_0', 0),
            (1, 'course_1', 0),
            (2, 'course_2', 0),
            (3, 'course_3', 0),
            (4, 'course_4', 1),
            (5, 'course_5', 1),
            (NULL, 'course_6', 1)
) AS C (course_ID, course_title, program_ID)

SELECT program_ID, program_title
INTO #programs
FROM (
    VALUES  (0, 'program_0'),
            (1, 'program_1')
) AS P (program_ID, program_title)
```

and after that execute the query

```
SELECT P.program_title, COUNT(C.course_ID) AS courses_amount
FROM #courses C
INNER JOIN #programs P ON C.program_ID = P.program_ID
GROUP BY P.program_ID, P.program_title
```

So you basically `GROUP BY` the value to which you to aggregate to and `COUNT` the 'course_id'.
`COUNT(C.course_ID)` only counts actual values and will ignore NULLs.
If you want to count the NULLs as well, just use `COUNT(*)`.

EDIT: Forgot the result...
So it'll look like this:

| program_title | courses_amount |
| --- | --- |
| program_0 | 4 |
| program_1 | 2 |

Comment: Thank You, I did this query in three different ways using  (JOIN and USING, JOIN and ON, Natural JOIN) clauses.